# The future perfect tence

Tags: grammar

Which is right: It's Christmas Eve...The children are in bed now. Dad is putting the decoration on the Christmas tree.Tomorrow morning when kids wake up, they will be surprised to learn that the tree *will have been decorated/is decorated/was decorated/has been decorated* by their Dad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context, context, context! Any of them may be right, depending on what exactly you mean. Here are just a few examples.

> They expect to participate in decorating the tree at Christmas next month; they will be surprised to learn when I call them tomorrow that the tree will already have been decorated by my Dad before they arrive on Christmas Eve.
>
> In their family, the children always decorate the tree; they will be surprised to learn that in our family the tree is decorated every year by my Dad.
>
> In our family the children usually decorate the tree; when they arrive tomorrow for Christmas Eve dinner they will be surprised to learn that the tree was decorated this year by my Dad.
>
> They expect to participate in decorating the tree tomorrow; they will be surprised to learn that the tree has been decorated already by my Dad.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the question. Could you tell me which is right now?

Comment: Either *has been* or *was* would fit here; I'd go with *has been* if what they are surprised at is the fact that the tree is now decorated, with *was* if what they're surprised at is who decorated it. Beyond this, in the first case, I'd use *see* rather than *learn*: *They'll be surprised to see..*